# How can I enable the firewall via command line on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, firewall

I can use the Security & Privacy preference pane to enable and disable the firewall, but how can I do it with the command line - something with `defaults write` maybe?

[image: Picture.png]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enable the application firewall via

```
defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 1
```

(0 to disable), and restart the services

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.alf.useragent.plist
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.alf.agent.plist

launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.alf.agent.plist
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.alf.useragent.plist
```

The application firewall can be controlled with the `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw` binary.

See [here](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/command-line-alf-on-mac-os-x/) for further information.

Note that the application firewall is entirely different from the BSD packet filter, that can be configured with the [`ipfw`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html) command line utility.

Comment: You need to `sudo` the unload & load of the daemon (/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.alf.agent.plist); otherwise it'll try to unload & load them from the user launchd, which won't work right.  Do not, however, `sudo` the commands for the useragent.

Comment: On newer versions of macOS restarting the services will fail because of "Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged". Disabling SIP is not recommended and quite difficult. As a workaround, restart the computer

Answer (score 4):

With MacOS Mojave, you can enable the MacOS Application Firewall with:

```bash
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate on
```

For more information check out the socketfilterfw man page or:

`/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw -h` (for help)

I did not have to unload or load the daemon (com.apple.alf)

Using `socketfilterfw` amends the plist `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf.plist` setting `globalstate` to 1 (on).